# Hotswap code with lambda fails, indicating that the method cannot be deleted

Tags: java, lambda, bytecode, hotswap

### Problem

Hotswap lambda failed.

### Process

I try to hotswap a Method body containing lambda.

#### 1. Hotswap Code

```
public class Example {
    private int x;
    public void print (int y) {
       Consumer<Integer> consumer = (key) -> System.out.println(key);
    }
}
```

#### 2. An example

```
 //Methods after sugar removal
First use code 1 to compile a class and put it in the directory, then run code 2 hot change
        //from static to instance method failed
        1、Consumer<Integer> consumer = (key) -> System.out.println(key);     
        2、Consumer<Integer> hot = (key) -> System.out.println(key + "" + this);
        //After desugar method
       private static synthetic lambda$print$0(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
       private synthetic lambda$print$1(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V

        //change static method params count successful
        String str = "args";
        Consumer<Integer> methodCount1 = (key) -> System.out.println(key);
        Consumer<Integer> methodCount2 = (key) -> System.out.println(key + str);
        private static synthetic lambda$print$2(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
        private static synthetic lambda$print$3(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Integer;)V

        //change instance method params count failed
        Consumer<Integer> instanceCount2 = (key) -> System.out.println(key + "" + this);
        Consumer<Integer> instanceCount3 = (key) -> System.out.println(key + str + this);
        private synthetic lambda$print$4(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
        private synthetic lambda$print$5(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Integer;)V


        //from nothing add or delete lambd  successful (compile static method)

        //from nothing add or delete lambd  fail (compile instance method)
        Consumer<Integer> instaceMethod = (key) -> System.out.println(this);
        private synthetic lambda$print$6(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
        hot.accept(1);
        consumer.accept(1);
```

#### 3. Hotswap type code

The agent code

```
   public class JavaAgent {

        public static void agentmain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("开始热更新");
            // 获得所有已被装载的class文件
            Class[] classes = inst.getAllLoadedClasses();
            for (Class clazz : classes) {
                if (clazz.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(agentArgs) || clazz.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("com.jason.Normal")) {
                    System.out.println(clazz.getName());
                    inst.addTransformer(new ClassFileTransformer() {

                        @Override
                        public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {

                                //System.out.println("hotswap class name :" + className);
                                String str = "";
                                if (className.contains("Example")){
                                    str = "Example.class";
                                }else if (className.contains("Norm")){
                                    str = "Normal.class";
                                }else {
                                    return null;
                                }
                                byte[] bytes = fileToBytes(new File("C:\\hot\\"+str));
                                return bytes;
                        }
                    }, true);
                    // 重转换
                    inst.retransformClasses(clazz);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("热更新结束");
        }

        public static byte[] fileToBytes(File file) {
            try {
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[in.available()];
                in.read(bytes);
                in.close();
                return bytes;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
     }
```

The hotswap code

```
     public class HotSwap {
         public static void hot(){
                try {
                    List<VirtualMachineDescriptor> list = VirtualMachine.list();
                    for (VirtualMachineDescriptor vmd : list) {
                            VirtualMachine virtualMachine = null;
                            virtualMachine = VirtualMachine.attach(vmd.id());
                            // 获得代理类位置 + 传递参数
                            virtualMachine.loadAgent("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Downloads\\JavaHotSwap-master\\JavaAgent\\target\\agentmain.jar", "com.jason.Example");
                            virtualMachine.detach();
                    }
                } catch (AttachNotSupportedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (AgentLoadException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (AgentInitializationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }  
}
```

The main code

```
int i = new Random().nextInt();
        new Example().print(i);
       // Normal.show();
       // System.out.println("hot");
        HotSwap.hot();
        new Example().print(i);
       // Normal.show();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Exception

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallAgentmain(InstrumentationImpl.java:411)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to add a method
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:144)
    at com.jason.JavaAgent.agentmain(JavaAgent.java:60)
    ... 6 more
com.sun.tools.attach.AgentInitializationException: Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgent(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:121)
    at com.jason.HotSwap.hot(HotSwap.java:23)
    at com.jason.Main.main(Main.java:33)
Agent failed to start!
Exception in thread "Attach Listener"
```

#### 3. Thoughts

I  know when bytecode is compiled, the instrument cannot change (add, delete, modify) methods.
Why can I modify static methods at will but can't modify an instance method?

Comment: As a side note, you should simplify your agent code by using [`Files.readAllBytes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-). Besides that, do you understand how lambda expressions are compiled (and that the exact result is compiler specific)? As then, it would be useful to print the actual “methods after sugar removal”, which determine whether the change is possible or not (which makes the question entirely independent from lambda expressions).

Comment: Another point to understand, is that once you added a `ClassFileTransformer`, that transformer stays registered. It is not removed after the next `retransformClasses` call. So there’s no sense in calling `addTransformer` with the same transformer implementation in a loop and you have to be aware that these transformers still exist when you load another agent.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry， but i Cannot modify， [I put the de sugar code in GitHub](https://github.com/scaleorjava/hot/blob/master/code), and It's not a loop. It's just for the convenience of getting hot after startup, and then exiting

Comment: In your agent code, you have a loop, `for (Class clazz : classes) { …` and install the same transformer for every matching class, despite one transformer would already be enough. Besides that, why can’t you modify your question? Just hit the [edit] link. But you didn’t answer the important question, do you understand that lambda bodies are compiled to synthetic methods and only those methods matter? In other words, the lambda expressions are entirely irrelevant, the behavior would be the same for ordinarily declared methods.

Comment: Don't allow modification until you give me a link, Maybe it's a lack of prestige

Comment: What I understand is that the body of the lambd method is compiled to generate a method. By capturing variables or other things, change the signature of the compiled method, but HotSwap successful or fail (static or instance)

Comment: Exactly. As you stated “*instrument cannot change (add, delete, modify) methods*”. That’s what the specification says. Apparently, in the case of the HotSpot JVM, this restriction has been lifter for `private static` methods, which can be added or removed, hence, also changed. I just tried it in the debugger with ordinary methods and it works as well. That’s all. As said, it’s not lambda specific.

Comment: I tried，It's true. I'm sorry that my test is not comprehensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stumbled over [JDK-8192936](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8192936). According to the bug report, a change made around Java 6 made the implementation accept changes regarding the addition or removal of `private static` and `private final` methods, despite the specification continued to state that this is not supported.

So when a lambda expression is desugared into a `private static` method, which applies to all lambda expressions not capturing `this`, changing them happens to work.

For lambda expressions capturing `this`, the behavior is compiler-dependent. It has become common to desugar them into a `private` instance method without `final` modifier, hence, they are not affected by the reported behavior. But in principle, a compiler could add the redundant `final` modifier. It’s also possible to convert the body of such a lambda expression into a `static` method, accepting the `this` reference as a parameter. That happened with older compilers.

The fix according to the report is not to consider the “*These restrictions may be lifted in future versions*” statement of the specification, but rather, to remove the feature to match the specification literally. There will be an option, `-XX:{+|-}AllowRedefinitionToAddOrDeleteMethods` to toggle the behavior starting with JDK 13, for some time.